# How to run sql script on every EF migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I want to run some custom Sql after *every* migration. I was hoping there was a global event or something I could tap into instead of putting my code in each individual migration.

What am I doing? I'm going to traverse the dbcontext via reflection to find enums to dump the key/values into an 'enum' table. The table won't be used anywhere, it's just for reference.

Thanks!

Comment: after every migration individually, or just every time an update is made you want to be sure to capture it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the seed method of the configuration class: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3

Comment: Thanks. I had incorrectly thought seed was run only on the first migration.

This solution will get run every time the data context is verified which in my case every time my MVC site is launched. Not exactly what I asked for but it's good enough.

Comment: Actually you can change an enum without it being a migration so maybe your way is better.

Comment: It should only run if you have a schema change. I wrap mine so that they are only added if they don't exist: if (!context.Races.Any()) { add race codes }

Comment: It runs whenever you try and update the database. (Even if there turned out to be no outstanding migrations).

Comment: (I have tested it and also it says so in the article I was reading)

Comment: Right, seed gets run when you do an update-database regardless of schema changes, but not on every launch of the app. That's why I test for existence in there.